# How to cross out a word in LaTex

Tags: formatting

How can I cross out a word in a sentence in Latex without using a package?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
%BeginDocument
The first \xcancel{three commands} work in text mode also i.e.,\xcancel{science}
%End Document
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I've edited your posting the tag "tikz-styles" as you've stated you want to accomplish the task without using a package -- `tikz` is a package. I've also deleted the 'color' tag.

Comment: What do you mean by “cross out”? Drawing a cross over it or just a horizontal line?

Comment: Without using a package? Then you'd just be implementing half of `cancel.sty` yourself?!?!

Comment: I'm new in latex and I have no idea how to use it. what does it mean please half of cancel.sty @kahen

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: drawing a cross over it please @egreg

Comment: why do you not want to use a package, why do you want to implement this yourself, especially if you are new to latex?

Comment: @ Andrew \documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
%BeginDocument

    The first \xcancel{three commands} work in text mode also i.e.,\xcancel{science}
%End Document
\end{document}

Comment: @ David Carlisle I used the package cancel which cross over a word but usually it's used for mathematical equations, and the professor didn't accept it and he told me if you use a package so you're doing nothing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your professor should know better. This teaches nothing about LaTeX, in my opinion; using packages *is* the way.

But here it is; it includes a (perhaps too clumsy) implementation of Euclid's algorithm for the greatest common divisor, in order to pass a correct pair of values to `\line`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crossout}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.05\dimen@}%
  \settoheight{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \count@=\dimen@
  \divide\count@ by \unitlength
  \count0=20 \count4=\count@
  \loop
  \count2=\count0 % keep a copy
  \divide\count2\count4 \multiply\count2\count4
  \ifnum\count2<\count0
    \advance\count0 -\count2 % the remainder
    \count2=\count0
    \count0=\count4
    \count4=\count2
  \repeat
  \count0=20 \divide\count0\count4
  \count2=\count@ \divide\count2\count4
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put(0,0){\line(\count0,\count2){20}}
  \put(0,\count@){\line(\count0,-\count2){20}}
  \end{picture}%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This word is \crossout{crossed} out

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, presenting this solution would be cheating. And, no, it won't work in all cases, due to strict limitations on the pairs accepted by `\line`. Your professor *surely* knows that TeX doesn't draw oblique lines.

With the *standard* package `pict2e` it's easier and it will work in any case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crossout}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \settowidth{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{0.05\dimen@}%
  \settoheight{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \count@=\dimen@
  \divide\count@ by \unitlength
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
  \put(0,0){\line(20,\count@){20}}
  \put(0,\count@){\line(20,-\count@){20}}
  \end{picture}%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This word is \crossout{crossed} out

\crossout{word}

\crossout{U}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A different solution (pdftex or luatex only)

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crossout}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{#1}%
  \dimen\z@=\wd\z@
  \dimen\tw@=\ht\z@
  \dimen\z@=.99626\dimen\z@   % get big points
  \dimen\tw@=.99626\dimen\tw@ % get big points
  \edef\co@wd{\strip@pt\dimen\z@}%  just the number
  \edef\co@ht{\strip@pt\dimen\tw@}% just the number
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\pdfliteral{q 1 J 0.4 w 0 0 m \co@wd\space \co@ht\space l S Q}}%
  \rlap{\pdfliteral{q 1 J 0.4 w 0 \co@ht\space m \co@wd\space 0 l S Q}}%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is \crossout{crossed} out

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the professor must be @wipet. ;-)

Comment: @egreg do you know how to cross it out with a wavy line, please?

Comment: @Sarah Maybe with `ulem` or `soul`

Comment: @egreg I tried this: The most \uwave{\hspace{1cm}}\crossout{powerful} processor in your  \crossout{computer} is probably the graphics processor , and I got a wavy line between the word most and the word powerful but I want the word to be cross out with a wavy line. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Sarah That's a new question.

Comment: @egreg yes, and I'm trying with ulem package by using \uwave but it's for underlining words

Comment: @Sarah I was meaning: ask a new question on the site.

Comment: @egreg oh sorry

Answer (score 3):

Your Professor wants you to learn TeX, he is a wise man! Try the below code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \makeatletter
    \newbox\@tempboxb
    \def\cancel#1{%
      \leavevmode
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{#1}
      \setbox\@tempboxb\hbox{x}
       \hbox to 0pt{\hbox to \wd\@tempboxa {\color{red}\leaders\copy\@tempboxb\hfill\kern0pt}}#1}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
This is \cancel{a very long word}
\end{document}
```

The approach is to put the words in a box and measure the width. Then draw a rule (using leaders, you can use any symbol such as `x` or `-`) over it. A package such as `ulem` will use more sophisticated macros to provide methods to adjust the cross lines, underline etc...